# Apache doesn't work when I try to deploy flask app using YOLOv8

Tags: apache, flask, yolov8

I try to deploy a Flask app which uses YOLOv8 library, using Apache httpd server. I have a problem, because YOLOv8 is a very heavy library and when I run Apache on a script importing this library, Apache perpetually restarts itself:

[Mon Mar 04 20:36:16.613768 2024] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9484:tid 300] AH00456: Apache Lounge VS17 Server built: Jan 30 2024 19:01:23

[Mon Mar 04 20:36:16.613768 2024] [core:notice] [pid 9484:tid 300] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\Apache24\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/Apache24'

[Mon Mar 04 20:36:16.615768 2024] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9484:tid 300] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 2500

[Mon Mar 04 20:36:16.957768 2024] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2500:tid 368] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.

[Mon Mar 04 20:36:22.694991 2024] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9484:tid 300] AH00428: Parent: child process 2500 exited with status 255 -- Restarting.

[Mon Mar 04 20:36:22.711990 2024] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9484:tid 300] AH00455: Apache/2.4.58 (Win64) mod_wsgi/5.0.0 Python/3.9 configured -- resuming

The problem is not with my whole app being too complex, because I tried some simple "Hello world" kind of scripts and Apache worked. Only if I added "from ultralytics import YOLO" line of code, the problem appeared. And for my whole app, YOLO is necessary, so I must use it.

Does anyone know how to solve that? I read, that there is some 4096 bytes limit in Apache and that heavier files cause the problem I mentioned. But is there any way to solve that?

UPDATE:
I have actually found a solution. I just imported all the ultralytics dependencies and THEN I imported ultralytics itself.

import matplotlib
import cv2
import PIL
import yaml
import requests
import scipy
import torch
import torchvision
import tqdm
import psutil
import cpuinfo
import thop
import pandas
import seaborn
from ultralytics import YOLO

Comment: Actually, I have found a solution. I just needed to import "manually" all the dependencies of ultralytics to import ultralytics itself:                                                                                 import matplotlib
import cv2
import PIL
import yaml
import requests
import scipy
import torch
import torchvision
import tqdm
import psutil
import cpuinfo
import thop
import pandas
import seaborn
from ultralytics import YOLO